# Are the unitary group, the special unitary group and the projective special unitary group quotiented by a U(n-1) subgroup reductive?

Tags: lie-groups

Are the unitary group, the special unitary group and the projective special unitary group quotiented by a U(1) subgroup reductive? For example is SU(n)/U(n-1) a reductive homogeneous space?

Comment: What's the action $U(1)$ on $SU(n)$?